# GATE uses all memory , hang application and gives Out Of Memory exception - Heap space issue

Tags: java, parsing, nlp, gate

I am using GATE nlp to parse documents. When some document with encrypted text get processed in pipeline, first it will hang the application for some time and later it throws OutOfMemory exception. I also increased the server size, but problem continues(time interval exception is thrown is reduced).
I had also added below content of GATE  document:

```
Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently noreply invite.freelancer.com Technical details of permanent failure DNS Error Address resolution of invite.freelancer.com. failed DNS server returned answer with no data Original message X Google DKIM Signature v 1 a rsa sha256 c relaxed relaxed d 1e100.net s 20130820 h x gm message state to from date message id subject mime version content type content transfer encoding content disposition precedence auto submitted bh ZqQVC blyigSDolCexcBuA0XSkdadZbW1Lz203WjYh0 b CfgWFuF LrpKhBqdK1hC8PnmAWaZKItgYacEdn d5DM1zMJTy9ZeJqohr 7AFQAxZ6 Lo3TALSjPpWCcWc84fhbgPpvcD7Y69BDCVaACFB2ZzmQdr1irz6NNnueEb7w1qi7uSJE WkcngEigf2m 0tcEwImBqEP04XePEpEcqu RYVMH9btl2U 9BqkDwOELAtRTIJ0XagDW G7SskYC4WkuJ78ZbfE1QAPPvKC 30hCKKhJ6luMcZMo2KeVndhVFFGG fNw8jc2dJBMZ aPkMYJQuhTzmoBqFZm5nuye2aoALwmtQs5ruu0rN4NhQo4cFHHtSd37R3Smy kq4JdTp FEkw X Gm Message State ALoCoQn2hyCwZttbqWrKGcY7eFT folV18HO iA3QqGNI6QajO7jelDjfb0gK9C8eWA3rakzTYMZCSL2PEeBdC9mw4zL35er5a 8qKX3h Sota EsEQtDA8LjLmMj5rq0SaDqtR21ZPOh18LHiZ0q7f374ntefjZnPjY SJ wIdNddiZfZB0ANM4AwSYfBbJ5wDYNxtORqDX X Received by 10.112.142.232 with SMTP id rz8mr4452539lbb.74.1433949006695 Wed 10 Jun 2015 08 10 06 0700 PDT To noreply invite.freelancer.com From candidate abc Date Wed 10 Jun 2015 08 10 06 0700 Message ID Subject Auto Reply Re  invites you to Freelancer MIME Version 1.0 Content Type text html charset UTF 8 Content Transfer Encoding base64 Content Disposition inline Precedence bulk X Autoreply yes Auto Submitted auto replied End of message
```

Comment: When **large no of documents**, is that all within the same request/transaction or multiple, concurrent requests/transactions?  Is this a cluster?  Add more nodes with load balance?  Add a throttle to limit concurrent requests?

Comment: I am processing large no of documents one by one on a standalone server. So at a time only a single request is there on server.

Comment: I have a near-similar problem with version 8.1, What you have in your pipeline? How big every document?

Comment: I am having Gazetter LKB and Jape Rules. For document you can consider any resume.

Comment: Your Jape rules? Are you using a lot of `+` and `*` in your patterns? In that case, you can reduce the memory footprint by using Kleene operators instead. Does it really occurs after big set of documents, are you sure that you don't have a big/complex document in the middle of your set?

Comment: @YMomb Yes I am having Jape Rules with + and * in my pattern and we are also having big documents to process.

Comment: It is often a good practice to for your memory to replace operators `+` and `*`  by Kleene operators for range like `[1,n]` or `[0,n]` (where `n` is the maximum number of occurences). This can save a lot of memory!

Comment: @Ymomb comments are very useful. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are retaining the JSONObject which is the one using most of the memory. It can be many times the size of the original file/input string.

If you want to free up memory don't retain it.  Ideally you should use a SAX style parser and process the file as you read it so it doesn't matter how big the file is.

In short, only retain the object if you need it and if you do be ready to make sure you have enough memory.

Comment: I am using GATE to get annotated(extract information) data as a JSON. I am returning JSON object to use for further processing.

Comment: @RGG in that case you need enough memory to hold that data.